# subscribe to array of observables using mergeMap

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a few observables and REST endpoints to which I subscribe/call and get data.

I want to get all data from observables and REST endpoints and create a variable with these to send it to a REST endpoint

I am using `forkJoin` and `mergeMap` as follows:

```
const sources: Array<Observable<any>> = [
      of(this.dataStore.trips$),
      of(this.dataStore.passengers$),
      of(this.dataStore.user$),
      of(this.dataStore.user$.pipe(
        mergeMap(user => <Observable<any>> this.userService.getUserIdByEmail(user.email))
      )),
      of(this.toursStore.totalInCart$),
      of(this.toursStore.totalInCart$.pipe(
        mergeMap(total => <Observable<any>> this.currencyService.getUSDConversionRate(total)),
      ))
    ];

forkJoin(sources).subscribe(
      observables => {
        const data = observables.map(observer => this.convertObservableToBehaviorSubject(observer, observer.source.value));

        console.log(data);

        booking = {
          booking: {
            created_at: Date.now(),
            trips: data[0].value,
            passengers: data[1].value,
            total: data[4].value,
            user_id: data[3].value,
            total: data[5].value,
          },
          user: data[2].value
        };

        console.log(booking);
      },
      err => console.log('Error:', err)
    );
```

The method to convert an observable into BehaviorSubject:

```
convertObservableToBehaviorSubject<T>(observable: Observable<T>, initValue: T): BehaviorSubject<T> {
    const subject = new BehaviorSubject(initValue);

    observable.subscribe(
      (x: T) => {
        subject.next(x);
      },
      (err: any) => {
        subject.error(err);
      },
      () => {
        subject.complete();
      },
    );

    return subject;
  }
```

When I `console.log(data)` I get all data, but when I try to assign the values to the variable `booking` I get undefined for **user_id** and **total**

```
this.dataStore.user$.pipe(
   mergeMap(user => <Observable<any>> this.userService.getUserIdByEmail(user.email))
)
```

and

```
this.toursStore.totalInCart$.pipe(
        mergeMap(total => <Observable<any>> this.currencyService.getUSDConversionRate(total)),
      )
```

I expect `user_id` and `total` to have data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step back a second and you can make this much simpler

You don't need to surround your observables with a `of(...)` because they are already an observable in the first place. `of` should be used to pipe an object into an observable.

Just use forkjoin with an object (like a dictionary) of the observables you already have ie. `forkJoin({trips: this.datastore.trips$, passengers: this.datastore.passengers$, etc)`

This means you will get the values immediately instead of having to convert them into a `BehavourSubject`.

So the end result will be

```
forkJoin({trips: this.datastore.trips$, passengers: this.datastore.passengers$, etc...})
  .subscribe(data => {

        booking = {
          booking: {
            created_at: Date.now(),
            trips: data.trips,
            passengers: data.passengers,
            ...etc
          }
        };
  })
```

Comment: Apparently the requests are fired properly against REST endpoint, though I can't subscribe to forkJoin!

Comment: I don't quite understand.. Can you elaborate?

Comment: When I wrap observables in ```of(...)``` I can subscribe to ```forkJoin``` but when I use ```forkJoin``` as you suggested without ```of()```, subscription doesn't excute

Comment: Ah right! This will be because `forkJoin` will wait until all of your observables have completed. I think `combineLatest` is what you are looking for instead.